# How to autoplay an anchor tag with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, jwplayer6

I have a player and an anchor as a button. When I click on the button, I take its id via JavaScript and send it to the server. I take back from server, the URL that should start playing in the player. (I am using jwplayer) I am obligated to use links for the android version of the page, because jwplayer doesn't have it properly covered. But I also need to protect my streams with tokens, and that's why I should take a new stream from the server each time the button is clicked.

My problem is that I don't know how to make the stream play, after is taken from server. 
Example code:

```
    <div id="myElement">Loading the player...</div><br><br>
    <a     href="javascript:loadVideos('http://content.jwplatform.com/manifests/bkaovAYt.smil','http:/    /content.jwplatform.com/manifests/bkaovAYt.m3u8');">Big Buck Bunny trailer</a><br><br>
    <a     href="javascript:loadVideos('http://content.jwplatform.com/manifests/i8oQD9zd.smil','http:/    /content.jwplatform.com/manifests/i8oQD9zd.m3u8');
">Tears of Steel trailer</a><br><br>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
jwplayer("myElement").setup({
    playlist: [{
        image: 'bunny.jpg',
        sources: [{
            file: 'http://content.jwplatform.com/manifests/bkaovAYt.smil'
        },{
            file: 'http://content.jwplatform.com/manifests/bkaovAYt.m3u8'
        }]
    }],
    height: '450',
    width: '800',
    androidhls: 'true'
}); 

function loadVideos(rtmp,hls) {
    jwplayer().load([{
        sources: [{
            file: rtmp
        },{
            file: hls
        }]
    }]);
    jwplayer().play();
} 
</script>
```

What I want to achieve is this:

```
<div id="myElement">Loading the player...</div><br><br>
<a href="javascript:loadVideos(data,data1);">Big Buck Bunny trailer</a><br><br>
<a href="javascript:loadVideos(data,data1);
">Tears of Steel trailer</a><br><br>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
jwplayer("myElement").setup({
    playlist: [{
        image: 'bunny.jpg',
        sources: [{
            file: 'http://content.jwplatform.com/manifests/bkaovAYt.smil'
        },{
            file: 'http://content.jwplatform.com/manifests/bkaovAYt.m3u8'
        }]
    }],
    height: '450',
    width: '800',
    androidhls: 'true'
}); 

function loadVideos(rtmp,hls) {
    jwplayer().load([{
        sources: [{
            file: rtmp
        },{
            file: hls
        }]
    }]);
    jwplayer().play();
} 
</script>
```

'data' and 'data1' will be the URLs send back from server. 
The user will click the button, which will cause the call to server, once the answer is back. How do I play it?

I hope I can get some advice from you guys.

Kind regards!

Comment: what about creating a new function? `getVideoStreams($id)` and this calls the server and then executes `loadVideos`? or am I misunderstanding?